# Why the defines inside a c++ namespace works outside the namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I use some macro defines in a namespace, then why should they work outside the namespace? Check this code for example:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

namespace foo {
    #define a x*2

    int f(int x) {
        return a;
    }
}

int main() {
    int a = 50;
    std::cout << a << endl;

    std::cout << foo::f(4) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here I have never wrote using namespace foo. But still this code doesn't get compiled because, when try to declare int a, it gets disturbed by previously defined a. But why this should happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"... when try to declare int a, it gets disturbed by previously defined a. But why this should happen?"*

The `#define` statement is interpreted by the c/c++ preprocessor that has no notion of namespaces (or any other c++ language constructs).

If you want to limit the extent of a definition, use an `#undef` directive:

```
namespace foo {
    #define a x*2

    int f(int x) {
        return a;
    }
    #undef a
 // ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: re "or any other c++ language constructs", for the use as `#if` conditions the preprocessor supports a subset of C expressions. It's worth noting that those expressions do not include C++'s `false` and `true` literals. Testing just now for the in-practice, g++ accepts them but Visual C++ does not.

Comment: This answer is correct, yet I would like to expand on the terminology. The preprocessor step occurs before the parsing and is, technically, handling a distinct language. IE all directives such as `#include` are expanded and then the resulting pre-processed source is parsed and the AST (abstract source tree) is created. You can dump the pre-processed output by invoking `gcc -E`.

Comment: @os_ It's clear enough (and was at least accepted) IMHO. You may try to edit to improve.

Comment: OK, I've just expanded this answer with a few preprocessor notes. Please review.

Comment: @os_ Rejected, as I don't see major improvement.

Answer (score 4):

The pre-processor does not know anything of high-level language features such as namespaces or scoping. It just looks for lines starting with `#` and then does simple text replacement. This is one reason why using the pre-processor for anything but `#include` or file-guards is dangerous in C++.

Answer (score 3):

`#define` does not respect any C++ scope. There is no such thing as a `"local" #define`. It'll be in effect until it is `#undef-ed`.

```
namespace foo {
    #define a x*2

    int f(int x) {
        return a;
    }
    #undef a              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C preprocessor is pretty much a language of it's own. It's executed first. Macros create code that is passed into actual C/C++ compiler. Whenever you use macros, always remember that macros trump everything, even curly braces. Only another preprocessor directive, like #undef, can stop a macro.

BTW, you can even use C preprocessor alone, on any text file.